# How Do I Boot? Installed Ubuntu on a Live Drive, when trying to boot it on an HP laptop it sends me straight to GNU GRUB 2.04

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

im trying to transition a HP laptop from POPOS! to Ubuntu.
Im using the same method I used before to install POP, create a live drive with my desired distro (ubuntu in this case) and have the bios read the USB drive before booting.
I tested this drive on my Mac 2017 and the drive worked without any issues both with Linux Mint and Ubuntu, I also tested it on another HP laptop from 2015 and it worked without issues as well.\

This specific laptop reads the USB to then sends a quick boot error (it's so quick I can't really read it) and sends me directly to **GNU GRUB 2.04** once here I really don't know what to do, I've searched for answers but they're usually about already having Ubuntu installed and it sending them to GNU GRUB, the usual answer is to fix it with a live drive boot and/or some GNU GRUB commands.
So, does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Comment: What model HP? What version of Ubuntu? If new system, you need newest Ubuntu, to have latest kernel & drivers for support of newer systems. What boot mode UEFI or BIOS? If nVidia, you may need safe boot mode.

Comment: @oldfred I fixed it, i was making the bootable drive with Balena Etcher, i reformatted the drive and used unetbootin and it finally worked, but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
The problem was BalenaEtcher I changed to Unetbootin and it finally worked.(I dont have windows anymore so RUFUS wasn't an option)